# World Topographic Map in QGIS is blocky pixelated

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

The ArcGIS World Topographic Map in QGIS is pixilated, specifically the text and lines.
View the images below in **full screen** to see the blocky pixelation.

How can the World Topographic Map be added to QGIS without the blocky pixelation?

Web Map: [ArcGIS World Topographic Map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?layers=30e5fe3149c34df1ba922e6f5bbf808f)

Map Details: [World Topo Map Details](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=30e5fe3149c34df1ba922e6f5bbf808f)

XYZ Tile source: https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/519/

[image]

[image]

Comment: are those scales exactly the same or is QGIS interpolating to fit a scale that is not provided by the server?

Comment: Echoing @IanTurton you may look at https://gisforthought.com/qgis-openstreetmap-scales/ to set scales matching the one of your tiles. If the scale you have in your map does not match the ones of the tiles, your tiles will look blurry/pixelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of Max. Zoom Level number. If you click edit option on XYZ tiles(which yours is ESRI-Standard), you will see this parameter. Just increase it to 18. If it isn't enough quality, you can set it to 19. But 20 or more than 20 can cause to "Image data not available" problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Xi Jin, this is helpful. I also changed the Projected CRS to "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator". This also helped to clear up the image.